# Run current Java file in Eclipse as a Java application after the click of a toolbar icon

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working just with simple Java projects that contain files with the main method. In NetBeans IDE I can customize the toolbar icons and insert one to Run my current Java file automatically Run current file Shift + F6:
[image: Run current file Shift + F6] without any prompts.

I would like to do the same in Eclipse. Is there a way to do that in Eclipse so that it run my Java file automatically without any prompts (such as: Run on Server, Run as Java Application, etc.).?

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl+F11 for Run command in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> for running the Java application.

First press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>J</kbd>. <kbd>J</kbd> for the Java application. Like that if you want to run on server  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>R</kbd> for the server.

[Eclipse Shortcut For Running Application in Diff. mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTDhd.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and clear explanation. What I exactly need is to know if there is a way to insert an icon in the toolbar for it to be clicked and automatically run the current file as a java application.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the class in either the Project Explorer or Package Explorer, mouse over either Run As or Debug As, and click Java Application.